# Redirecting page 1 to default permalink

Tags: redirect

I have issue with wordpress redirection.

Like i want 
http://example.com/slideshows/test/1/
But its redirecting to 
http://example.com/slideshows/test/
Please help its urgent for me.

Answer (score 0):

- Re-save permalinks `Settings --> Permalink --> Save settings`
- try access to http://example.com/slideshows/test/page/1/ or http://example.com/slideshows/test/paged/1/
- Problem with your plugin/code